# The calculation of Conventional non-tripping current and Conventional tripping current of MCB

Tags: circuit-protection

IEC 60898-1 defines the Conventional non-tripping current and Conventional tripping current of a circuit breaker is 1.13In and 1.45In. But why these two numbers? Well, the normal wave of power network may have been taken into consideration. How to calculate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't expect a 10A fuse to blow at (say) 10.5 amps but 13% above this at 11.3 amps you might expect a fuse to eventually blow. It's exactly the same with circuit breakers and they both have the 13% overload point meaning the CBs/fuses should not trip if they were at this level all day. On the other hand, the 45% overload level should trip after 1 hour and at 155% overload (2.55 times rated current) it should trip after one minute.

However there are different breaker technologies that will accelerate this: -

[image]

Data taken from [here](http://w3.usa.siemens.com/us/internet-dms/btlv/circuitprotection/ieccircuitprotection/docs_HeavyDutySafetySwitches/SIE_CA_5SY5-TripCurve.pdf) and note that is just shows the thermal part of the breaker's characteristic. The magnetic part handles the much bigger overload currents.

Comment: and adding to what Andy says,  The magnetic trip portion in a circuit breaker has no time delay.

Comment: Thanks, It helps me to understand these two numbers when you put them in the form of percentage. Well, I wanted to know how the editors of standards calculate them. But this question doesn't make much sense.:)

Comment: @AsaMyth you need to look into European fuses to understand the 1.13 and 1.45 - how good at history are you?

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. Actually I am not good at European history, not to mention Europe fuses history... Could you give me some references on this?

Comment: I don't know of anything - just plain ordinary memory did the trick for me and googling!